# get key for object NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have a NSMutableDictionary which holds NSArrays. for example:

```
NSArray *food = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"pasta", @"bread", nil];
[myDictionary setObject:food forKey:@"toEat"];
NSArray *drink = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"sprite", @"cola", nil];
[myDictionary setObject:drink forKey:@"toDrink"];
```

To access all values, i use the code:

```
NSArray *allValues = [[myDictionary allValues] valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.self"];
```

Is there any way to remove one specific object? for example to remove "cola" from UITableView i have to find the key for this object.

```
NSString *key = [myDictionary allKeysForObject:@"cola"];
NSMutableArray *allArraysForKey = [myDictionary allObjectsForKey:key];
[allArraysForKey removeObject:@"cola"];
[myDictionary setObject:allArraysForKey forKey:key];
```

I can't figure out where is the problem? myDictionary allkeysforobject doesn't show the key for "cola"

Comment: I would try making it an NSMutableArray to start then removing the object at index.

Answer (score 1):

The object `@"cola"` is not a key within your dictionary. There is an array that contains the object `@"cola"` but there are no instances of the object itself. Therefore `allKeysForObject:` doesn't return anything.

You probably also want to be careful with `[[myDictionary allValues] valueForKeyPath:...]`. `allValues` returns all the values in no defined order. So the net effect of your call is permitted to change massively between calls due to any unrelated change whatsoever, or even due to no change whatsoever, and that behaviour isn't required to be constant between devices or versions of iOS.

A more conventional approach would be a plain array holding your objects, which would name a name (like 'cola') and a type ('food' or 'drink'). You could sort on type to form your sections.